# Force to use http build cache gradle

Tags: android, caching, gradle

I want force to use `httpBuildCache` and not `local build cache` with gradle

I configure my `seeting.gradle` with this :

```
buildCache {
local {
    enabled = false
}
remote(HttpBuildCache) {
    url = 'url'
    push = true
    credentials {
        username = '*'
        password = '*'
    }
}
}
```

But when I start two build, I have this error :

```
Could not create service of type FileHasher using GradleUserHomeScopeServices.createCachingFileHasher().
```

I have tried to rm `/caches` of my `.gradle`.

but I didn't understand why and when I start build with property `local cache disable` gradle create new cache in local.

Comment: Can you add the `-s` flag and post the stacktrace this should produce?

Comment: could you please mark the answer

Comment: Hi ! You cannot use same local cache with two builds. If u use Docker don't persist local cache. 
Even if we do not indicate to use the local cache, it will still lock files that will create an error.